# Why puma staging environment does not start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

When I try to start my web-server in `staging` environment it does not run.
But in `production` environment with same as configuration - everything is ok.

Where can be the error?

My config for puma is:

```
deploy_to = ENV['CURRENT_PATH']

workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 3)
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 16), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16)
daemonize       true
preload_app!
backlog = Integer(ENV['PUMA_BACKLOG'] || 20)

directory       "#{deploy_to}/current"
pidfile         "#{deploy_to}/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path      "#{deploy_to}/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.state"
stdout_redirect "#{deploy_to}/shared/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{deploy_to}/shared/log/puma.stderr.log"
bind            "unix://#{deploy_to}/shared/tmp/sockets/kiosk.sock"
activate_control_app "unix://#{deploy_to}/shared/tmp/sockets/pumactl.sock"


on_worker_boot do
  # worker specific setup
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

***upd***

puma.stdout.log

```
=== puma startup: 2016-01-28 09:54:11 +0000 === 
[14731] * Starting control server on unix:///home/ubuntu/staging/shared/tmp/sockets/pumactl.sock 
[14731] - Worker 0 (pid: 14794) booted, phase: 0 
[14731] - Worker 1 (pid: 14814) booted, phase: 0 
[14731] - Worker 2 (pid: 14829) booted, phase: 0 
[14731] - Gracefully shutting down workers... 
[14731] === puma shutdown: 2016-01-28 09:55:17 +0000 === 
[14731] - Goodbye!
```

Comment: Which error do you get when trying to start in `staging`?

Comment: @Vasfed update a post

Comment: I meant rails' log, most likely `log/staging.log` or in console, depending on how your logging is set  up, it seems that there's something not related to puma itself

Comment: @Vasfed oh, sorry.by the way, `staging.log` is blank

Comment: Try starting `rails server -e staging` without puma, just to ensure rails is able to run in staging (db and other configs, etc)

Comment: @Vasfed yes, all is ok, I try it already